# How do I properly create a web service request in mule4 to POST a work email address to Workday?

Tags: mule4, workday-api

I'm creating an api in mule4 that needs to POST a users work email address to Workday, but I keep getting validation error. I'm using the Workday Human Resources Connector with operation Change_Work_Contact_Information.

Error:
Subject person must have exactly one primary work email address in order to have non-primary entries. The primary contact information may be either previously entered or included within this request.

This is the entire validationError:

```
SoapFault{faultCode={http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Client.validationError, subCode=null, detail='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><detail><wd:Validation_Fault xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"><wd:Validation_Error><wd:Message>Subject person must have exactly one primary work email address in order to have non-primary entries. The primary contact information may be either previously entered or included within this request.</wd:Message><wd:Detail_Message>Element 6$111091 Restricted by 103$71804</wd:Detail_Message><wd:Xpath>/wd:Change_Work_Contact_Information_Request[1]/wd:Change_Work_Contact_Information_Data[1]/wd:Person_Contact_Information_Data[1]/wd:Person_Email_Information_Data[1]</wd:Xpath></wd:Validation_Error><wd:Validation_Error><wd:Message>Email Data and Usage Data elements are required unless email is being deleted.</wd:Message><wd:Detail_Message>Element 6$111110 Restricted by 103$65597</wd:Detail_Message><wd:Xpath>/wd:Change_Work_Contact_Information_Request[1]/wd:Change_Work_Contact_Information_Data[1]/wd:Person_Contact_Information_Data[1]/wd:Person_Email_Information_Data[1]/wd:Email_Information_Data[1]</wd:Xpath></wd:Validation_Error></wd:Validation_Fault></detail>', reason='Validation error occurred. Subject person must have exactly one primary work email address in order to have non-primary entries. The primary contact information may be either previously entered or included within this request.', node='null', role='null'}
```

I used Workday's wsdl to build the body of the request to send users employeeId along with the email address. I'm using the following in my transform message:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns ns0 urn:com.workday/bsvc
---
{
    ns0#Change_Work_Contact_Information_Request: {
        ns0#Change_Work_Contact_Information_Data: {
            ns0#Person_Reference: {
                ns0#ID @(ns0#"type": "Employee_ID"): payload.employeeId
            },
            ns0#Person_Contact_Information_Data: {
                ns0#Person_Email_Information_Data: {
                    ns0#Email_Information_Data: {
                        ns0#Email_Data: {
                            ns0#Email_Address: payload.email,
                            ns0#Email_Comment: p('workday.createEmailMessage') as String default ""
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need help understanding if I'm missing something in my body of the request or am I using the wrong Workday Connector/Operation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the Communication_Method_Usage_Information_Data/Communication_Usage_Type_Data/@Primary Attribute? There has to be a primary email set to allow for non-primary (non-indicated) emails to be input.

Edit:

For security for this Business Process, you need to go to the Work Contact Change Business Process, then Edit the Business Process Security Policy.

Update the Initiating Action section for the Web Service Request or Public REST Request with the Integration System User Group or Group that is being used.

Comment: Hi Wyatt, i was able to solve my issue but would you know what rights i need in WD?      `ns0#Usage_Data @(ns0#Public: true): {
       ns0#Type_Data @(ns0#Primary: true): {
        ns0#Type_Reference: {
         ns0#ID @(ns0#"type": "Communication_Usage_Type_ID"): "WORK"`

Comment: I added details for security setup in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

the following is the answer:

> ```
>                   ns0#Usage_Data @(ns0#Public: true): {
>                       ns0#Type_Data @(ns0#Primary: true): {
>                           ns0#Type_Reference: {
>                               ns0#ID @(ns0#"type": "Communication_Usage_Type_ID"): "WORK"
> ```